# Google Play detecting new permissions after using Android Studio

Tags: java, android, permissions, android-studio, google-play

I have just switched from Eclipse to Android Studio and when I updated my app, the google play store found three new permissions in my new exported apk.
I am quoting the manifest file and the gradle file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.appsbyusman.simplecolorwallpaper"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.1" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />

<!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <!-- This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services. -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <!-- Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.appsbyusman.simplecolorwallpaper.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

The build.gradle of my module is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.appsbyusman.simplecolorwallpaper"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 21
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile project(':ambilWarna')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
}
```

As you can see there are three permissions declared in the manifest but the play store detects the following permissions:

```
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE maxSdkVersion=18
android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE maxSdkVersion=18
```

I am using a color picker module and google ads, I made the project on eclipse and imported in Android Studio.

EDIT:
Adding to the same question, I just uploaded another app, this time I removed some permissions and removed some libraries, but this time, I got very strange permissions. Please look at this screenshot I'm attaching.[image]

EDIT 2:
Never mind, I found out it was due to my inclusion of play services's whole package instead of merely using Ads package

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation on `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission:

> Allows read only access to phone state.
>
> Note: If both your minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion values are set to 3 or lower, the system implicitly grants your app this permission. If you don't need this permission, be sure your targetSdkVersion is 4 or higher.

From the documentation on `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission:

> Allows an application to write to external storage.
>
> Note: If both your minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion values are set to 3 or lower, the system implicitly grants your app this permission. If you don't need this permission, be sure your targetSdkVersion is 4 or higher.

From the documentation on `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, permission:

> Allows an application to write to external storage.
>
> Note: If both your minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion values are set to 3 or lower, the system implicitly grants your app this permission. If you don't need this permission, be sure your targetSdkVersion is 4 or higher.

So, you need to set your `targetSdkVersion` to 4 or higher. As your `targetSdkVersion` is set to 21 in both manifest and `build.gradle`, the only place to look at is `ambilWarna` module. If is has `targetSdkVersion` of 3 or less, manifest merger may assume that you have some code here which needs to read/write external storage/phone state and add these permissions to your app during the build.

BTW, you can remove following lines from the manifest because Gradle will use the values specified in `build.gradle` file (which are the same in your case) instead:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

Comment: Wow your solution worked! I changed minSdkVersion to 7 and targetSdkVersion to 18 in ambilWarna as I found there: https://github.com/dpkirchner/ambilwarna Can changing them manually be destructive? My app works fine though

Comment: I don't see the way these new values may be destructive. :) `minSdkVersion` is used to inform the Android OS about the minimal API version that is required to run this app (`minSdkVersion` of your app module is 11, so changing this value in library will not affect the app behavior in any way). `targetSdkVersion` is used to tell Android OS under which API version you tested your app so it won't enable any compatibility behaviors, which is also not destructive. More info can be found here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Comment: I just experienced a similar issue, please see the updated question. I'll really appreciate your answer!

Comment: I just experienced a similar issue. Please see the updated question. I'll really appreciate your reply!

Comment: Never mind, I found out it was due to play services's whole package instead of merely using Admob